# How to filter by not exact text JS

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Here is a part of ag-grid JS code that filter cells with exactly text:

```
function doesExternalFilterPass(node) {
  switch (status) {
    case 'released':
      return node.data.Status == 'Released';
    case 'early-access':
      return node.data.Status == 'Early access';
    case 'in-development':
      return node.data.Status == 'In development';
    case 'rtt-strategy':
      return node.data.Genre == /.'RTT'./;
    default:
      return true;
  }
}
```

For example, one of the strings filter all cells containing *Released* in Status column, other containing *RTT* in Genre column. **But I need that strings like *RTT, RTS, Action* also to be filtered.** As I understand, I should use regular expressions, I try this

```
return node.data.Genre == /.'RTT'./;
```

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas to get many-words filtering?

Comment: `Something == Regex` doesn't make sense. Do you mean `/.'RTT'./.test(node.data.Genre)`? This is a funny-looking pattern in any case, but I'm not sure what you're trying to match exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need regex for this. Regex should be avoided, if possible. If I understand it correctly, you want to check if a string contains a substring. For that you can use `String.prototype.includes()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes
   Example code:

```
case 'rtt-strategy':
  return node.data.Genre.includes('RTT');
```

2. If you still want to use regex, then you can use the `RegExp.prototype.test()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test. First of all, you really should look up how to use regex in js, because your example code is way off. Secondly, example code:

```
/RTT/.test(node.data.Genre)
```

Or if you want case insensitive, then:

```
/RTT/i.test(node.data.Genre)
```

Comment: The first option, I get an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
The second option seems to be working,

Comment: @СергейЯкушин that either means that `node.data.Genre` is sometimes `undefined`, so property `Genre` sometimes does not exist on `data`, or that you made a typo or another mistake somewhere else. Neither however means that you have to use regex because of it. If `Genre` is an optional prop then you can have a fallback to an empty string:
`(node.data.Genre ?? '').includes('RTT');`
This way if `Genre` does not exist you will get empty string instead and call the `includes` method on it.

Comment: the code `return (node.data.Genre ?? '').includes('RTT');` looks like incorrect in validator and doesn't work (sorry, I am very poor at js, created a table combining existing patterns). Plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/9Zi3I9IZijl737y6?preview This function is in main.js on 53 string.

Also, why should I avoid to use regex?

Comment: @СергейЯкушин I checked your plunker and it works for me, eg:
`// Genre
    case 'tbt-genre':
      return (node.data.Genre ?? '').includes('TBT');
`
As for why not to use regex when it is not necessary, well there are a lot of discussions on this point. You can google it and you'll find many topics. Basically there are considerations about performance, readability, security and other aspects. In this case I would say regex is simply an overkill, you can do the same with built-in string methods.

Comment: I was wrong, this way works, the problem was JS validator that ISP Manager is using: https://i.imgur.com/DRrozB4.jpeg. It tells about many wrong things. In fact the code works despite this. Do you think this validating problem is insignificant?

Many thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: @СергейЯкушин I see. I don't know what JS validator is being used there but as I see it the error comes from the fact that it uses older version of JS which doesn't have "nullish coalescing operator":  `??`. You could work around it without the `??` like this:
`return node.data.Genre ? node.data.Genre.includes('RTT') : false;`
This is called the "ternary operator". Or you could just keep using the regex solution instead. It's not an issue in this case, it's just a general convention to not use regex if it is not necessary, but as I see it in this case the code is cleaner with it.